# Can PHP's simplexml include POST data in the request?

Tags: php, xml, post, simplexml

I'm loading an xml file with PHP's simplexml with GET variables in the URL.

`$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://localhost/service.xml?item=1")`

Is it possible to pass `item=1` as a POST variable instead of GET?

I'm fine with using something other than simplexml if necessary.

Comment: Not without some sort of form submit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get data with `curl` then load with `simplexml_load_string`

```
// Inıt curl
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://localhost/service.xml");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
// Set post fields
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "item=1");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
// get output
$output = curl_exec($ch);
// Close curl
curl_close ($ch);

// simplexml_load_string
$xml = simplexml_load_string($output);
```

Comment: Thanks this may be just what I need. Going to try implementation.